# filter rows if alphabetical letter from a (smiles) string not from a list of elements

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, bioinformatics

**QUESTION**

How to filter out the SMILES strings if any alphabetical letter (atoms) in the string, **insensitive to capitalization**, come from a dataframe of elements `H, He, Li, Be, B`? This is a truncated list, and there are 80 of them.

**BACKGROUND**

I have a database containing SMILES strings:

> The simplified molecular-input line-entry system (SMILES) is a specification in the form of a line notation for describing the structure of chemical species using short ASCII strings.

(More info [Wikipedia link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplified_molecular-input_line-entry_system))

The purpose of this was to get rid of rare elements and organometallics from the database.

I am starting with a string to test the code before proceeding to a data frame. I write loops to test for characters inside of a string.

```
strings = "[O+]#C[Ni-4](C#[O+])(C#[O+])C#[O+]"
list = ['Ni']
for i in list:
    if i in strings:
        print(i)
```

How to iterate over a dataframe and filter?

Comment: So what is your question? Which output do you get from your program?

Comment: If you check what `i` contains, you will find a problem with your approach: `for i in strings` grabs only one character at a time.

Comment: @usr2564301 Thank you! I write an answer based on your hint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the list/simplified version, do the opposite would work. Use the list to find matches in strings.

```
strings = "[O+]#C[Ni-4](C#[O+])(C#[O+])C#[O+]"
list = ['Ni', 'Sc']

for i in list:
    if i in strings:
        print(i)
else:
    print('nah')

> Ni
> nah
```

To loop over a dataframe, use `np.where`

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'smiles': ['sdflk', '[O+]#C[Ni-4](C#[O+])(C#[O+])C#[O+]']})
list = ['Ni', 'Sc']

df['element'] = np.where(df.smiles.str.contains('|'.join(list)), 1, 0) # mark element that contains string in the list as 1, else 0
df[df['element'] == 1] # remove rows that have the element
```

Note that this would be problematic when the dataframe contains `Sc1` like string, where `S` and `c` actually mean sulfur and carbon on a simple aromatic ring rather than the Scandium `Sc`. So we need a way to recognize `Sc` only and only if there is no number attached to it. **Negative lookahead** would help us right here.

```
df['Sc'] = df['smiles'].str.match('Sc(?!\d)')
```